# Using an HttpWebRequest to access multiple pages

Tags: .net, vb.net, httpwebrequest, httpwebresponse

I'm trying to screenscrape a website that requires a POST login authentication.  I can authenticate fine on my first request, but when I attempt to turn back around and hit the next page, I get a redirect back to the login page (basically it's saying I'm not logged in).

Code:

```
Public Function GetPage(ByVal PageName As String, ByVal UserName As String, ByVal Password As String) As String
    Dim ReturnString As String = ""
    Dim Cookies As New CookieContainer
    Dim AuthURI As Uri = New Uri(AuthURL)
    Cookies.GetCookieHeader(AuthURI)
    Cookies.GetCookies(AuthURI)

    'Set Header/Meta Info
    System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Ssl3
    Dim request As HttpWebRequest = HttpWebRequest.Create(AuthURL)
    request.Method = "POST"
    request.CookieContainer = Cookies
    request.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U;Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.8.1.1) Gecko/20061204 Firefox/2.0.0.1"

    'Set POST Info
    Dim postData As String = "userName=" & HttpUtility.UrlEncode(UserName) & "&password=" & HttpUtility.UrlEncode(Password)
    Dim byteArray As Byte() = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(postData)
    request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
    request.ContentLength = byteArray.Length

    'Write to the request stream
    Dim dataStream As Stream = request.GetRequestStream()
    dataStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length)
    dataStream.Close()

    ' Get the response.
    Dim response As HttpWebResponse = request.GetResponse()
    dataStream = response.GetResponseStream()
    Dim reader As New StreamReader(dataStream)
    Dim responseFromServer As String = reader.ReadToEnd()
    ReturnString = responseFromServer

    'Append cookie data
    For Each c As Cookie In response.Cookies
        Cookies.Add(c)
    Next

    ' Clean up the streams.
    reader.Close()
    dataStream.Close()
    response.Close()

    'Bail on fail
    If ReturnString.Contains("Login failed") Then Return Nothing

    'Generate new request
    request = HttpWebRequest.Create(URLStub & PageName)
    request.Method = "POST"
    request.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U;Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.8.1.1) Gecko/20061204 Firefox/2.0.0.1"
    request.CookieContainer = Cookies

    'Set POST Info
    postData = "userName=" & HttpUtility.UrlEncode(UserName) & "&password=" & HttpUtility.UrlEncode(Password)
    byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(postData)
    request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
    request.ContentLength = byteArray.Length

    'Write to the request stream
    dataStream = request.GetRequestStream()
    dataStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length)
    dataStream.Close()

    'Get the response.
    response = request.GetResponse
    dataStream = response.GetResponseStream
    reader = New StreamReader(dataStream)
    responseFromServer = reader.ReadToEnd
    ReturnString = responseFromServer

    'Clean up the streams.
    reader.Close()
    dataStream.Close()
    response.Close()

    Return ReturnString
End Function
```

This code mimics another page which is written in PHP.  The PHP code page works and I'm using the same URLs as the PHP version is, so I'm about 99% sure that the problem doesn't lie on the server end.

Also I've scoured other posts on this matter, and it **appears** that I'm doing everything right syntax-wise, but maybe I'm missing something small and stupid?

Any ideas?  I've been fighting this for a couple of days now.  Thank you in advance. :)

---

**EDIT :** I've been playing with the session cookies and have been comparing between the initial logon and the actual request.  Here's what I've got:

```
FIRST:
ORA_WX_SESSION: "1FAA2AB1EF40DF4BC291DD3326F1DC3C596F56CF-2#3"
JSESSIONID: a2c38b128e1e54051a2c95c5a3a1e3a4cb0cb5b7ba74cd260aaec531856d722f.e34SahmMbNaMe34Sa3yPaN8Sc40
XYZCustomerServiceUserName: (login-name)
XYZ: d53f8dcd87b861a61d99ac21ec53bb2b

LAST:
ORA_WX_SESSION: 1FAA2AB1EF40DF4BC291DD3326F1DC3C596F56CF-2#3
JSESSIONID: a2c38b128e1e54051a2c95c5a3a1e3a4cb0cb5b7ba74cd260aaec531856d722f.e34SahmMbNaMe34Sa3yPaN8Sc40
```

I notice two things... first, the ORA_WX_SESSION has its quotes stripped from it (even if I attempt to force them back in between response and request).  Also the XYZCustomerServiceUserName and XYZ values are stripped.  Other than that, the session information is identical between the two connection attempts.

Comment: I would guess something is coming back in response that you are not picking up.

Answer (score 0):

The thing that makes you log out can be anything which server wants from you and you have not supplied. We made a couple of automations using System.Net classes and it turns out that the best thing you can do is using [Watin](http://watin.org/) or [Selenium](http://seleniumhq.org/). We are using Watin. By using such a tool you are not affected by simple changes on the server side.